# Eigenvalues of a symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Consider a real symmetric matrix

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}m_1^2&\mu^2\\\mu^2&m_2^2\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then we find that, the eigenvalues are:

$$
\frac{1}{2}(m_1^2+m_2^2)\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(m_1^2+m_2^2)^2-4\mu^4}
$$

which is evidently complex if $4\mu^4>(m_1^2+m_2^2)^2$

So, what am I missing here? It must be something trivial.

Thanks

Comment: How are you finding the eigenvalues? Because those aren't the solutions I'm getting when I solve the characteristic equation

Comment: It is both: hermitian and symmetric

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is: $x^2-(m_1^2+m_2^2)x+m_1^2m_2^2-\mu^4=0$ we solve for $x$, so we find two solutions.

Comment: I just compute the determinant of $A-x1$ and set it to zero.

Comment: OK. a real symmetric matrix is hermitian. It doesn't matter. The famous theorem says that a hermitian matrix has real eigenvalues. Right?

Comment: Of course it matters. There is a tag for symmetric matrices, no tag for Hermitian matrices. People subscribe to tags. Proper tagging dictates how many people look at your question. Do you take pleasure in having no audience?

Answer (score 2):

No, the discriminant should be $\operatorname{tr}(A)^2-4\det(A)^2=(m_1^2+m_2^2)^2-4(m_1^2m_2^2-\mu^4)=(m_1^2-m_2^2)^2+4\mu^4$.

Comment: So, I have made a stupid sign error then.

Comment: @dbrane Two sign errors - which is good. You should always try to have an even number of sign errors :)

Comment: Yes. I also did not have my breakfast, which explains the sign error.